# How to extract something out of a file after greping?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

How can I extract `group-3-vm1` after I do this `grep`?

```
$ cat output/tpcds_query_1a_71_mr.out | grep "Tracking URL" | tail -1
```

Here's the result:

```
Starting Job = job_1442587212068_0126, Tracking URL = http://group-3-vm1:8088/proxy/application_1442587212068_0126/
```

Comment: Have you tried `cut` or `awk`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'extract'? Do you want the whole url or I've just misunderstood the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This awk command replaces the grep and tail commands while also extracting the text of interest:

```
$ awk -F'[:/]' '/Tracking URL/{n=$4;} END{print n;}' output/tpcds_query_1a_71_mr.out 
group-3-vm1
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[:/]'`

  This sets the field separator to either a colon or a slash.
- `/Tracking URL/{n=$4;}`

  This looks for lines containing `Tracking URL` and saves the fourth field in variable `n`.
- `END{print n;}`

  After we have reached the end of the file, this prints the last `n` that we found.

#### Example

Here is a sample test file and output:

```
$ cat output/tpcds_query_1a_71_mr.out 
Starting Job = job_1442587212068_0126, Tracking URL = http://group-1-vm1:8088/proxy/application_1442587212068_0126/
Starting Job = job_1442587212068_0126, Tracking URL = http://group-2-vm1:8088/proxy/application_1442587212068_0126/
Starting Job = job_1442587212068_0126, Tracking URL = http://group-3-vm1:8088/proxy/application_1442587212068_0126/
Starting Job = job_1442587212068_0126, No Track URL = http://group-4-vm1:8088/proxy/application_1442587212068_0126/
$ awk -F'[:/]' '/Tracking URL/{n=$4;} END{print n;}' output/tpcds_query_1a_71_mr.out 
group-3-vm1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat output/tpcds_query_1a_71_mr.out | grep "Tracking URL" | tail -1 | sed 's/.\+Tracking URL = http:\/\/\([a-zA-Z0-9\-]\+\).*/\1/g'
```

Some explanation.  This uses your solution but pipes the results through sed to strip everthing up to and include http:// and uses a group capture ((...)) to capture everything that's a-Z0-9 and -.  NOTE - If some of your hosts have underscores, you'll need to add _ to the capture characters.